# UITextfield removes when done-button clicked on tableviewheader

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextfield, swift4

I had a textfield on `TableViewCell`. when I click to Done button, textfield removes. when I scroll down and scroll up, textfield is visible again.

```
addSubview(search)

    search.leftViewMode = UITextField.ViewMode.always

    search.placeholder = "Поиск лекарств и товаров"
    search.backgroundColor = .white
    search.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    search.dropShadow(color: .black, opacity: 0.5, offSet: CGSize(width: 5, height: 5), radius: 5, scale: false)
```

Comment: You need to set your search objects properties first then you should call addSubview method otherwise you are probably adding a empty UIView then when you scroll it is adding the properties.  Sumary:  addSubview(search) should be at the end not at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

        self.searchTextFieldShouldReturn = true
        textField.resignFirstResponder()

        return true
    }
```